# Angular decimal pipe based on first positive decimal number

Tags: angular, numbers, pipe

I'm trying to show decimal for cryptocurrency listing in my Angular app using `| number` pipe. When coin is for example BTC I need to be showed as `$45,740.83` with 2 decimals. When you have something like ShibaINU I need to be showed as `$0.000029`. Am I able to achieve this using Angular number pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can, if you refer to the documentation

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

you are able to add a digitInfo parameter to the pipe, which allows you to determine

1. the number of digit
2. the decimal point

   {{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}

digitsInfo will be a string in the following format

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

So i believe in your case, it will look like this in your template

- BTC - {{ btcValue | number : '1.2-2' }}
- ShibaINU - {{ ShibaINU Value
  | number : '1.6-6' }}

Comment: Yeah, thats true. But the data are given in Array so I have them in ngFor loop. So I don't know the format (for example '1.6-6'). I need to do it dynamically. I was just interested if it is possible to achieve this in `| number` pipe given by Angular. I can create my own pipe but i was just interested if it's possible to use the original pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achive this through https://github.com/coingecko/cryptoformat